# React input field going out of focus when using forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-forwardref, react-phone-number-input

I have a `react-hook-form` that takes in user data. For the user's cellPhoneNumber, I am using `react-phone-number-input` library's `PhoneInputWithCountry`.

For my form, I have a 'Save Changes' button that becomes active or inactive based on the details entered.

```
.
.
.
<EuiFlexItem grow={false}>
              <EuiButton
                fill
                form={formId}
                isDisabled={!methods.formState.isDirty || userQuery.isError}
                isLoading={isFetchingOrPatchingUser}
                type="submit"
              >
                Save changes
              </EuiButton>
            </EuiFlexItem>
.
.
.
```

Following is the controller for my 'CellPhoneNumber' field:

```
<Controller
        name="cellPhoneNumber"
        render={({
          field: { ref, ...fieldProps },
          fieldState: { invalid, error },
        }) => (
          <EuiFormHookRow
            label="Cell Phone Number"
            error={error}
            isInvalid={invalid}
            fullWidth
          >
            <PhoneInputWithCountry
              inputComponent={EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText}
              inputRef={ref}
              isInvalid={invalid}
              placeholder="Enter phone number"
              disabled={isDisabled}
              defaultCountry="US"
              international
              {...fieldProps}
              onBlur={() => {
                console.log('Blur Called', fieldProps);
                fieldProps.onBlur();
                trigger(['emailAddress']);
              }}
            />
          </EuiFormHookRow>
        )}
      />
```

Code for custom input:

```
const EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText = forwardRef<
    HTMLInputElement,
    EuiFieldTextProps
  >(function EuiCellPhoneNumberInput(props, ref) {
    console.log(props.onFocus);
    return <EuiFieldText {...props} disabled={isDisabled} inputRef={ref} />;
  });
```

Now, the `PhoneInput` component in itself works as intended, allowing me to udpate the cellPhoneNumber. But when I try and use the 'inputComponent' prop and pass in a custom input field using forwardRef, every time the form is re-rendered (mostly triggered by 'Save Changes' button being re-rendered) the custom input field goes out of focus. This does not happen when using the default input that comes with `PhoneInput` but when passing a custom input component, this behaviour is observed.

So the question is, why is this happening and is there a way to bring the custom input field back in focus.

I suspect this might be something related to forwarding refs or props. Feel free to follow-up any additional information you might need.

Thank you for the help.

References:

1. [react-phone-number-input library](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/)
2. [Custom Input prop link](https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/react-phone-number-input/#:%7E:text=setValue%7D/%3E-,Custom%20%3Cinput/%3E,-A%20custom%20inputComponent)

I tried changing the props and manually writing the `onChange` and `onBlur` methods but both of them didn't work. The code is still not behaving as intended when using customInput.

Comment: Somehow the custom input is getting unmounted and then remounted. I don't see exactly how from the code you've shown. The most likely cases would be if there's a react `key` that is changing on every render, or if a component type is changing on every render. Is `EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText` being defined inside some other component (which would cause it to be redefined on each render)?

Comment: @NicholasTower thank you so much for the insight! It was exactly the case that it was defined in another component which led it to be remounted. I defined the`EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText` as a separate component and it worked absolutely fine. 

Is there a way to mark a comment as the correct answer? I'd love to do that so that anybody with the same issue gets to see this.

Comment: `Is there a way to mark a comment as the correct answer?` No, but i've now typed it up as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As identified via the comments, the issue is this: `EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText` was being defined inside another component. Something like this:

```
const OuterComponent = (props) => {

  const EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText = forwardRef<
    HTMLInputElement,
    EuiFieldTextProps
  >(function EuiCellPhoneNumberInput(props, ref) {
    console.log(props.onFocus);
    return <EuiFieldText {...props} disabled={isDisabled} inputRef={ref} />;
  });


  // ...
  <PhoneInputWithCountry
     inputComponent={EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText}
     // ...
  />
};
```

The problem with this is that every time the outer component renders, it makes a brand new definition for EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText. It may have the same text as the last time, but it's a different function in memory. That means that when react compares the types of those two components, they will look like they are different component types. Thus, react is forced to unmount the old one and mount the new one. The new element does not have focus, so it looks like focus has been lost

The fix for this is to move EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText outside, so it it just defined once:

```
const EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText = forwardRef<
  HTMLInputElement,
  EuiFieldTextProps
>(function EuiCellPhoneNumberInput(props, ref) {
  console.log(props.onFocus);
  return <EuiFieldText {...props} disabled={isDisabled} inputRef={ref} />;
});


const OuterComponent = (props) => {
  // ...
  <PhoneInputWithCountry
     inputComponent={EuiCellPhoneNumberFieldText}
     // ...
  />
}
```